# Can you embed a Plotly chart from Jupyter Notebook into a tweet?

Tags: python, twitter, jupyter-notebook, plotly, embed

I created a Plotly graph objects chart in Jupyter Notebook and spent a lot of time customizing the hover label. I want to post the chart on Twitter and keep the hover functionality, but I'm not very familiar with online embedding.

**Is it possible to embed the Plotly chart in a tweet to maintain the hover functionality?**

Comment: I suppose you cannot do that, you can save it as image and then use it (but it will be static).

Comment: No, the Plotly interactive graph contains a lot of code, so it is way too long to fit in a tweet. Twitter allows you to add image (and other media) to tweets, where the tweet contains a link to the image, but that only works for a static file. Best is probably to upload the plot somewhere and link to it.